# writeShort in little Endian: hex shows big, but opening only works in le

Tags: java, endianness

I am a bit confused on what I have done..
As far as I know, java and especially the DataOutputStream writes values in Big endian.

I am writing a little signal generator and have to store the files in little endian. No problem so far, just swap the bytes.

`writeShort()` also says  "writing high byte first".

So for example decimal '2' would be stored normally as:

```
00 02 (big endian)
02 00 (little endian) is what I need.
```

So I swap the bytes:

```
public static short swap (short value)
{
        int b1 = value & 0xff;
        int b2 = (value >> 8) & 0xff;

        return (short) (b1 << 8 | b2 << 0);
}
```

and write the short:

```
dos.writeShort(swap(x[t]));
```

The hex editor shows me the file in the format it should be: `02 00`

When I now try to open my generated audio file, I can't hear anything. (audacity raw data import and settings like samplerate all correct).

I removed the byte swapping, getting a file with: `00 02` which is big endian.

I opened audacity again and with the same configuration, I heard the tone.
Definetely I configured little endian!

I copied the file to windows (I am working on a mac) and opened the file in Cool Edit 2000, choosing again 16khz, 16 bit unsigned pcm and little endian (16-bit LSB, MSB).
I heard the tone again, choosing big endian nothing.

Where is my failure? Something confuses me as this should not work like I described..

Generating the tone:

```
// x(t) = A*cos (2*pi * f * t + phi)
        // 
        if(null != dos) 
        {
            double sampPeriod = 1.0/16000;
            short x[] = new short[16000]; // 16k samples for 1 second
            for(int t=0; t < x.length; t++)
            {
                double time = t * sampPeriod;
                x[t] = (short) (amplitude * Math.sin(2.0*Math.PI*frequenz*time+phase));
            }

            for(int t=0; t < x.length; t++)
            {
                try {
                    dos.writeShort(x[t]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

Edited 2:16pm 02/04/13:
I was reading around assuming something in my understanding is the failure and I found the following picture on wikipedia:

[image: read access]

See answer of the problem in the next post.

Comment: `00 02` is not little or big endian by itself. It is `2` when interpreted as big endian and `512` when interpreted as little endian.

Comment: ok, this may be a discussion about how I described it and I understand what you want to say to me. But it doesn't help me at this moment.

Comment: as I was writing in my answer: This did help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys and everyone who is interested by following this question:

The failure has nothing to do with little or big endian.
Everything I understood from LE and BE was correct. (But not the assume at the end about read access, that tricked my mind as I was searching for *any* explanation..)

The failure was about the *amplitude* of the signal.

In case the amplitude was too low - the volume itself (which generates through amplitude) was too low. So nothing could be heard. Interpreting the written big endian file as little endian made every short-sample in the file a larger one (coming back to zch's comment: 00 02 is 512 when interpreted as little endian).

This generated a higher sampling value at that time and caused me to hear a thing.

By setting generally a higher amplitude *and* byte-swapping correctly to little endian I could again hear a thing. So the main failure was nothing about endianess.

zch's comment made me brood over again and again, resulting in a little c++ code on windows reading the values and seeing that native LE interpretation is the same as zch said. That lead me to the amplitude point and now I have found the problem. Hope no one else does this stupid failure or will find this post and know in the future :-)